# Number of matrices with zero determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, finite-fields

I want to count matrices over finite field with zero determinant. 
For example, the numbet of $2\times2$ matrices over $\Bbb{Z}_4$ with zero determinant is 88 by hand computations. 
On the other hand the size of the group $GL(2,4)$ is $180$ and the total number of such $2\times2$ matrices is $256$. 
So something is wrong. 
What is my mistake?

Revised question:
 I am looking for the number of $2×2$ matrices over $\Bbb{Z}_4$ (the ring of integers modulo 4), with zero determinant. By a quick computations, there are $88$ ones. So what is the formula in general?

Comment: It is hard to know your mistake if you don't show what you've done.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you call **z-4**?

Comment: Note that $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ is not a field; do you mean matrices over $\Bbb{F}_4$ in stead?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry. I mean Z_4=Z/4Z which is not a field. So is there any way to count the matrices with zero determinants?

Comment: @SeyedHadiJafari Add the information to the original question (rather than in comments) to clarify, and it can be reopened.

Answer (score 11):

Over a finite *field* of order $q$, it is easy to count matrices with nonzero determinant (and from there, get matrices with zero determinant by complementary counting).

There are $q^n-1$ choices for the first column: we just have to choose a nonzero vector in $\mathbb F_q^n$. Then there are $q^n-q$ choices for the second column: we must avoid choosing any multiple of the first column. There are $q^n-q^2$ choices for the third column (since there are $q^2$ distinct linear combinations of the first two columns, which we must avoid, and so on). So the number of $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb F_q$ with nonzero determinant is
$$
    \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (q^n - q^k)
$$
and then $q^{n^2}$ minus this product gives the number of matrices with zero determinant.

But $\mathbb Z_4$ (if by this you mean the integers modulo $4$) is not a field, and so this calculation doesn't quite work. For example, 
$$\det \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix} \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$ even though the second column is not a multiple of the first.

---

Here is a general formula for $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb Z_4$.

Write the matrix as $A + 2B$, where $A,B$ have entries from $\{0,1\}$.

Suppose that mod $2$, $A$ has corank $r$ (rank $n-r$). Then we can choose $r$ independent (mod $2$) vectors $\mathbf x_1, \dots, \mathbf x_r$ such that $A\mathbf x_i \equiv \mathbf 0 \pmod 2$. Extend these to a set of $n$ vectors that are independent mod $2$, and let $X$ be the matrix whose columns are these $n$ vectors.

Because $X$ is invertible mod $2$, $X$ is invertible mod $4$, so $\det(A + 2B) = \det(X(A+2B)X^{-1}) = \det(XAX^{-1} + 2 XBX^{-1})$. If we find a decomposition of $XAX^{-1} + 2 XBX^{-1}$ into $A' + 2B'$, where $A', B'$ have entries from $\{0,1\}$, then the first $r$ rows of $A'$ are $0$ and the last $n-r$ rows are linearly independent.

It follows that if $r \ge 2$, then $\det(A + 2B)$ is definitely $0$: a row expansion by the first row of $A' + 2B'$ picks up a factor of $2$, and a row expansion by the second row of $A' + 2B'$ picks up another factor of $2$. What about when $r=1$?

When $r=1$, we can factor out a $2$ from the first row of $A' + 2B'$. This lets us rewrite $\det(A' + 2B')$ as $2 \cdot \det(A'' + 2B'')$ where:

- the first row of $A''$ is the first row of $B'$, and other rows are taken from $A'$.
- the first row of $B''$ is $0$, and other rows are taken from $B'$.

If $\det(A' + 2B') = 2$, then $\det(A'' + 2B'')$ is odd, which means $A''$ is invertible mod $2$. Given the last $n-1$ rows of $A''$ (which were fixed by $A'$), $2^{n-1}$ out of $2^n$ choices for the first row of $A''$ (which comes from $B'$) will make $A''$ invertible mod $2$. Therefore half of the possible choices for $B'$ (which come from half of the possible choices for $B$) give determinant $2$ here. So **exactly half of the matrices with $r=1$ will have determinant $0$, and the other half will have determinant $2$**.

Thus, if we want to count the matrices mod $4$ with determinant $0$, let $N_0, N_1, N_{\ge 2}$ (with $N_0 + N_1 + N_{\ge 2} = 2^{n^2}$) be the number of matrices over $\mathbb F_2$ with corank $0$, corank $1$, and corank $\ge 2$. Then the number we're interested in is
$$
    N_1 \cdot 2^{n^2-1} + N_{\ge 2} \cdot 2^{n^2}.
$$
(When $A$ is counted by $N_{\ge 2}$, any matrix $B$ will make $\det(A+2B)=0$; when $A$ is counted by $N_1$, half of all possible matrices will do.) For example, when $n=2$, $N_1 = 9$ and $N_{\ge 2} = 1$, so there are $9 \cdot 2^3 + 1 \cdot 2^4 = 72 + 16 = 88$ matrices.

We have $N_0 = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2^n - 2^k)$ by the formula for the first section. Counting $N_1$ is a bit harder, but we can do it: if we first choose a linearly dependent row on the $i^{\text{th}}$ step ($i=0, 1,\dots, n-1$), the number of ways is $2^i \prod_{k=0}^{n-2} (2^n - 2^k)$, so altogether $N_1 = (2^n - 1)\prod_{k=0}^{n-2} (2^n - 2^k)$. So the general formula for $n \times n$ matrices of $\mathbb Z_4$ is
$$
 2^{n^2-1}(2^n - 1)\prod_{k=0}^{n-2} (2^n - 2^k) + 2^{n^2}\left(2^{n^2} - \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2^n - 2^k) - (2^n - 1)\prod_{k=0}^{n-2} (2^n - 2^k)\right).
$$
Some algebra simplifies this to
$$
    4^{n^2} - 2^{n^2-1} (2^{n+1}-1) \prod_{k=0}^{n-2} (2^n - 2^k).
$$
The sequence begins $1, 88, 100864, 1735131136, \dots$.

For $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ in general, similar reasoning should work.

Comment: Thanks. I mean the integers modulo 4 by Z_4. How could we count it?

Comment: @SeyedHadiJafari The case of 2x2 matrices modulo $p^2$ you can do by similarly grouping it according to the first column. If the first column is all zeros, any second column ($p^4$ choices) will give $\det=0$. If the first column is non-zero but contains only multiples of $p$, then $p^3$ choices for the second column give zero. And, the main case, when the first column has at least one entry not divisible by $p$, then $p^2$ choices for the second column work. With larger matrices it gets more complicated.

Comment: @SeyedHadiJafari Here is an an answer for $\mathbb Z_4$.

Comment: Good job coming with the analysis based on co-rank. Too bad I had already upvoted :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very nice.

Answer (score 3):

If you are counting matrices over $\Bbb{F}_4$, here's a useful fact:

> An $n\times n$-matrix over a field $k$ is invertible if and only if its columns form a basis for $k^n$.

I'll leave the proof to the reader. For $2\times2$-matrices over $\Bbb{F}_4$ this means the columns are two non-collinear vectors. So any choice of non-zero vector for the first column, and any choice of non-collinear vector for the second column yields an invertible matrix.

If you are counting matrices over $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$, then here's a useful fact:

> An $n\times n$-matrix over $\Bbb{Z}/p^k\Bbb{Z}$ is invertible if and only if it is invertible over $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$.

Again I'll leave the proof to the reader. This reduces the problem to counting invertible matrices over $\Bbb{F}_2$, which you can do using the first fact.

Comment: I'm not sure this helps (though it might, depending on why we're finding matrices with zero determinant). Exactly due to your hint, the non-invertible $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ are the ones with determinant $0$ or $2$, not just the ones with determinant $0$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I see your point; I had in mind counting invertible matrices. I'll wait for the question to be clarified a bit before I try to further this approach though.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for the number of 2×2 matrices over Z_4 (the class of integers modulo 4), with zero determinant. By a quick computations, there are 88 ones. So what is the formula in general?

Comment: I was hoping to use the second highlighted statement to tally the matrices with determinant two (modulo four), but they don't seem to easily fall into clean orbits of the group of invertible matrices. The upvote (for that observation) was, of course, there already.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I wrote this answer when the question was less clear; I wasn't sure whether it concerned matrices over $\Bbb{F}_4$ or $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$, and whether it concerned non-invertible matrices or matrices with determinant $0$. My suggestions here solve the problem for three out of four combinations, unfortunately it turned out that the question concerned the fourth combination. At this point I have nothing to add to Misha's excellent answer, so I'll leave it at this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach to counting $2\times2$-matrices over $\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$ with determinant $0$. I'll start with $p=2$ as an example, and then generalize the result to arbitrary $p$.

The number of $2\times2$-matrices with coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ with determinant $0$ is precisely the number of pairs of pairs 
$$((a,d),(b,c))\in((\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z})^2)^2
\qquad\text{ with }\qquad
ad=bc.$$
A simple multiplication table for $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ 
$$\begin{array}{r|cccc}
 &0&1&2&3\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&2&3\\
2&0&2&0&2\\
3&0&3&2&1
\end{array},$$
shows that there are $8$ pairs with product $0$, $2$ pairs with product $1$, $4$ pairs with product $2$, and $2$ pairs with product $3$. Hence the number of pairs of pairs with the same product is
$$8^2+2^2+4^2+2^2=88,$$
and so this is the number of $2\times2$-matrices with coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ with determinant $0$.

In the same way, making a multiplication table for $\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$ we count the number of pairs...

1. ... with product $0$. There are $3p^2-2p$ such pairs, yielding
   $$(3p^2-2p)=p^2(3p-2)^2,$$
   matrices with determinant $0$.
2. ... with *non-zero* product a multiple of $p$. There are $2p(p-1)^2$ such pairs, evenly distributed over the $p-1$ non-zero elements of $\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$ that are a multiple of $p$. So there are $2p(p-1)$ pairs for each value, yielding
   $$(p-1)\times(2p(p-1))^2=4p^2(p-1)^3,$$
   matrices with determinant $0$.
3. ... with product coprime to $p$. There are $p^2(p-1)^2$ such pairs, evenly distributed over the $p(p-1)$ elements of $\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$ coprime to $p$. So there are $p(p-1)$ pairs for each value, yielding 
   $$p(p-1)\times (p(p-1))^2=p^3(p-1)^3,$$
   matrices with determinant $0$.

Hence the total number of matrices with coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$ and determinant $0$ equals
$$p^3(p-1)^3+4p^2(p-1)^3+p^2(3p-2)^2=p^3(p^3+p^2-1).$$
For $p=2,3,5,7,11,\ldots$ we find the numbers
$$88,\ 945,\ 18\,625,\ 134\,113,\ 1\,931\,281,\ \ldots$$

Comment: Thank you very much